# Order conformation email not send to customer on guest checkout megnto 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with  magneto  email in guest checkout 
When i proceed to checkout  As a guest user email not come 
But if i register on account  then email working fine  I don,t know why this is happen  please help me i am new in magneto ,,

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent-magento-1-9-1

Comment: @Owais Aslam i already tried but Not issue with email issue on when i tried to checkout as guest then issue comes

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked any other cronjob disturb the functinality?
Starting with Magento 1.9.1 the emails are not being sent directly during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob - please ensure this has been set up and is running correctly. [check cron job](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron)

Please check below extension:

The extension [AOE_Scheduler](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) can help you in confirming that your Magento cronjob has been configured correctly and is running.

Comment: Does it affect the funcationality

Comment: well i comment  $isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;  this on cron .php then email workig fine for regster user but not for guest